# Handling features dependent on a data field that may not be present in sample

Tags: python, feature-selection, feature-engineering, anomaly-detection, isolation-forest

I'm trying to build an anomaly detection model using Isolation Forest. I currently have 12 features, about half of them depends on the presence of a particular data field, say `A`. For example, `feature_1` could be if `A` is longer than a specific length, and `feature_2` could be if `A` contains a certain substring. The problem is `A` may not be present for all data points. So I have 3 values for my features: `0` if `A` does not meet the criteria, `1` if it does, and `2` if `A` does not exist.

I have 2 datasets, one contains data points that I'm highly confident is anomalous, the other contains data points that I'm relatively confident should be benign. However, my model is predicting only a small subset of the first dataset as "anomalous".

It appears that a lot of the "benign" data samples have the value `2` for many of the features, because `A` does not exist in these data samples.

I'm wondering if using `2` to indicate the absence of `A` is affecting my results. How should I engineer my features then, or should I drop samples without `A`?

Comment: Are you saying that you have added a separate feature which encodes whether a particular column in the data is present? And this is also supposed to indicate whether some other features should be considered or not?

Comment: How do you wish datapoints that are missing A to be classified? Always benign, always anomalous, or dependent on the remaining data?

Comment: @JonNordby I don't have a separate feature to indicate whether a particular column in the data is present. I'm using the same column to indicate if `A` does not exist for that data point (value is `2`), and if it does exist, then `1` if it fits the criteria, `0` if it does not. I'm wondering if I should be doing this.

Comment: For datapoints that are missing `A`, their classification should depend on the remaining features.

Comment: I have tried to separate my dataset so that I only use features depending on the presence of `A` on datapoints that contain `A`. The results are a bit better - 33% of the anomalous dataset now get predicted as anomalous, compared to the previous 2%. I would then try to use features that don't involve `A` on the remaining datapoints that do not contain `A` (haven't tried this yet). So essentially 2 models. Not sure if this is better.

Comment: Two models and splitting instances based on the (missing) data, is what you need to do. Don't think there is any other way. You can package this into a single scikit-learn estimator / pipeline, so that this complexity is not seen from the outside.